Repository pattern with Prisma
folks! I am trying to use the Repository pattern with prisma, but I am facing type errors and wrong type inheritance
For this code:
class PostModel {
 static async findMany(obj?: Prisma.PostFindManyArgs) {
    return await db.post.findMany(obj);
  }
}
await PostModel.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: params.id,
      },
      include: {
        author: true,
      }
    })

I am getting
Post  | null

Instead of:
Post & {author: Author} | null

I tried to referring the type but without success
 static async findMany<T extends Prisma.PostFindManyArgs>(
    obj: T
  ): Promise<Prisma.PrismaPromise<Prisma.Result<typeof db.post, T,'findMany'>>> {
    return await db.post.findMany(obj);
  }


I found a way of doing it
export class PostRepo {
  static async findMany<T extends Prisma.PostFindManyArgs>(
    args: Prisma.SelectSubset<T, Prisma.PostFindManyArgs>
  ): Promise<Array<Prisma.PostGetPayload<T>>> {
    return await db.post.findMany(args);
  }
}

